# Fetch Files Related to opportunity in salesforce

Tags: opportunity, files, contentversion, contentdocument, salesforceexcelconnector

I want to run a SOQL query that fetches files associated with opportunities(in a particular stage). If I am not wrong content version is the actual object I need to be querying on to fetch content? Here is the query I am running

```
SELECT IsAssetEnabled, Checksum, ContentBodyId, ContentLocation, ContentModifiedDate, Origin, ContentUrl, ContentDocumentId, Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Description, ExternalDataSourceId, ExternalDocumentInfo1, ExternalDocumentInfo2, FeaturedContentBoost, FeaturedContentDate, FileExtension, SharingPrivacy, FileType, IsDeleted, FirstPublishLocationId, LastModifiedById, IsLatest, LastModifiedDate, IsMajorVersion, OwnerId, NegativeRatingCount, PathOnClient, PositiveRatingCount, SharingOption, PublishStatus, RatingCount, ContentSize, ReasonForChange, SystemModstamp, TagCsv, TextPreview, Title, ContentModifiedById, VersionData, VersionNumber 
 FROM ContentVersion
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I add the column in the query that tells me what opportunity is this file associated with, plus how do I fetch files associated with the opportunity in XYZ stage only?
2. I am running this query in G-connector for salesforce, when the above query runs I get the data in spreadsheet, how do I convert this data to the actual file png, JP, Pdf whatever it is, to make it usable for other application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SSE.

You will have to do separate queries.

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId in ( SELECT Id FROM Opportunity where StageName = 'XYZ'  ) and LinkedEntity.Type='Opportunity'
```

Once you have the **ContentDocumentId**, please query [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) for the column **VersionData** which stores **base64** format which can then be converted as per your need.

```
select VersionData from contentversion where contentdocumentid in ('069XXXXXXXXXXXX','069YYYYYYYYYYYY')
```

where ('069XXXXXXXXXXXX','069YYYYYYYYYYYY') is comma separated values of Content Document Id

Please check following apps to download/extract files:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iz0jEAC
https://www.sfdcfileexporter.com/sffxhome/

I suggest you go through [Salesforce SOAP API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) which provides detailed information about the objects/tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying to run a  query in a tool 'G-connector for salesforce'. I am not sure if  I can  run 3 different queries in a single tab? Is there a way to create a nested query that queries all 3 objects, opportunities, ContentDocumentLink, ContentVersion?

Comment: My usecase is that I want to export all the files that are attached to all the opportunities that are in XYZ stage. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Anonymous I have updated my answer with a new nested query and some tools to be used for downloading/extracting files.